# How to convert from observable to promise in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-promise

I want to create a promise out of an observable. I have the following two functions

```
public getData(info: Info): Promise<Data> {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     this.getObsData(info).subscribe((data:Data) => {
       resolve(data);
       }
   });
}

getObsData(info: Info): Observable<Data> {
    this.anhttpservice(a,b,c).switchMap(data=>
     return Observable.create(observer=> {observer.next(new Data(data))});
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error from `getObsData()` as shown below.

`error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

I am new to angular 2 and promises/observables so I must be doing something obviously wrong

Comment: You're not returning your Observable. `return this.anhttpservice(a,b,c).switchMap(data=>
     return Observable.create(observer=> {observer.next(new Data(data))}); `

Comment: Thanks that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using your IDE to autocomplete after calling an Observable ? ...

```
this.getObsData(info).toPromise();
this.anhttpservice(a,b,c).toPromise();
```

(Altough I recommend sticking to observables, but it's your choice)

Comment: Good point about the IDE. I am using eclipse with eclipse-typescript from palantir which is less than desirable with autocomplete and other modern features. What do you use?

Comment: I'm on Visual studio code, which is very complete. You can also use Atom, or even Sublime Text. This is Javascript, you have a very wide range of choice there !

Comment: You should absolutely use Visual Studio Code. By far the most complete text editor / IDE for TypeScript and Angular

Comment: If I may recommend some plugins on it, go for TSLint, Typescript Hero, Auto import. This gives you code styling, auto importing, import sorting, and much, much more.